# Number of integers in a certain range with certain properties

Tags: algorithms

How would one (quickly) find the number of integers in the range [1, x] for some x, more than half of its digits being one digit, given that $x$ has at most, say, 19 digits.

Brute force would obviously not work in a reasonable amount of time (where "reasonable" means roughly $10^9$ seconds)

Comment: I'm assuming this is some kind of programming challenge, isn't it?

Comment: It is essentially this problem from an old contest:http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=435 , but the solution that has been given is not well explained at all

Comment: Is it decimal or binary? Do I understand correctly that it is the number of integers having each more than half their digits being $1$ ... or did you mean something else, for example half the digits are the same digit?

Comment: Do you remove leading 0?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Decompose the range $[1,x]$ into more manageable ranges of the form $[N\cdot 10^{k+1},N\cdot 10^{k+1} + d \cdot 10^k)$, where $d < 10$. Enumerate over the "popular" digit, and use inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: This gets a large portion of it, but what about the cases $\ge 10^{\lceil \log x\rceil}$

Comment: Here is an example: $[0,1234] = [0,1000) + [1000,1200) + [1200,1230) + [1230,1234) + 1234$.